# NextAuth + Firebase: how to addDoc for a user created from nextauth's firestore adapter

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next-auth

I am using NextAuth + Firebase where I set up the authentication using NextAuth's FireStoreAdapter as per this documentation. Everything including user sessions and authentication in-app works as intended, but I am seeing two inconsistencies in the firebase dashboard.

1. It doesn't actually 'create user' in firebase and thus shows nothing on the authentication -> users page

[image]

2. My current addDoc code creates a new user field based on user's email and adds a collection to that newly created user. For example, the "j1WM8uo[...]" is the user object created from nextauth; but addDoc-ing collection from my code creates a new "XXX@gmail.com" object and adds collection on that object.

[image]

This is my current addDoc code. As you can see I'm using `session?.user?.email!` to reference the current session's user, but how do we link the reference to the "j1WM8uo[...]" user object instead?

```
const doc = await addDoc(
        collection(db, 'users', session?.user?.email!, 'chats'),
        {
          userId: session?.user?.email!,
          createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
          AIRole,
          myRole,
          topic,
        }
      );
```

Comment: did you find a fix?